# Salesforce Report : Multiple leads from same Org

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, reporting

I am trying to build a report in Salesforce which will give me all those **Leads with Same Domain Name and Count is more than 2**.

If Lead Email is abc@abc.com then the domain is abc.com.

For Example: Let's assume there are 6 leads available in a Salesforce org.

Lead 1, Domain => outlook.com
Lead 2, Domain => outlook.com
Lead 3, Domain => outlook.com
Lead 4, Domain => right.com
Lead 5, Domain => right.com
Lead 6, Domain => right.com
Lead 7, Domain => yes.com
If I run the report, it will only return **three leads for outlook.com domain and right.com domain** as they have the same domain and count is more than 2.

Thanks, Soumen

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have created the formula field and used that field to group rows. But I am not able to figure out, how to display only that group which contains more than 2 rows